# "User removed": who was removed? And what is the -2 due to?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts, profile-page

I just saw this in my rep tab:

[image]

The screenshot was taken on Saturday, January the 7th, around 15:03 in the Italian time zone, that is GMT+1, just before asking this. I was wondering:

> What user was removed to cause this? Why were they removed? And what exactly was the -2 due to?

I don't mind losing 2 rep, I'm just curious as to why I lost it, i.e. who and why was removed and how he had given me those 2 points. I am guessing an accepted answer: is that so?

Comment: There are many different scenarios to arrive at any given rep number; as to *who* got removed, that information is intentionally not shown to you.

Comment: @ACuriousMind so I guess there is no way to know how that rep number was arrived at in my case, right?

Comment: None aside from guessing, no.

Comment: A +2 comes from either accepting an answer or from an approved suggested edit at low rep. So if the -2 comes from canceling the reputation result of a single action it would have been one of those. However, it could also represent the loss of a *net* +2 coming from say, one up vote on a question  from the user and three downvotes that you cast on that user's posts. Or any other combination that get to +2 on net.

Comment: @dmckee Huh, who knew. It seems the interaction in question was [this suggested edit](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/103625), where the second approving user was removed; it [seems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244693/184688) that that will cause a rollback of the +2 rep from the suggested edit. I wouldn't think that that would (/should) happen, but there you are.